# FMU import and export of Simulink and openModelica

Tags: obsolete

Is there a way for FMU import/export to/from Simulink and Modelica models?

If anyone could help in FMU would be much appreciated.

Comment: OpenModelica guys have a collection of tutorials here: https://openmodelica.org/useresresources/modelica-courses 
Especially, they have some helpful video tutorials, here: https://spoken-tutorial.org/tutorial-search/?search_foss=OpenModelica&search_language=English Unfortunately, I do not see anything on FMU import/export in that list.

Comment: Please tag this quetions with FMI Simulink also

Answer (score 2):

FMI import and Export is very tool specific.

Regarding Simulink import / export: which tooling do you want to use?

Native support by Mathworks (for newer Simulink versions)?

- Import: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/in-product-solutions.html
- Export: https://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/export-model-as-tool-coupling-fmu.html  (needs runtime installation and license)
- Export with Simulink Compiler
  (needs additional license):
  https://mathworks.com/products/simulink-compiler.html#standalone-mockup,
  for fixed-step solver only

Or e.g. FMI-Kit (open source) from Dassault Systems (export with Simulink Coder for fixed-step solvers):

- https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMIKit-Simulink
- https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMIKit-Simulink/blob/master/docs/fmu_export.md
- https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMIKit-Simulink/blob/master/docs/fmu_import.md

Or another third party solution?